# Placemark iconContent как добавить html-контент

Tags: yandex-maps-api

API 2.1
На карту нужно добавить метку с текстом из нескольких строк.
использую:

```
iconContent: '<div><i>Офис:</i><br/><b>Название</b><br/>Адрес</div>',
preset: "islands#orangeStretchyIcon"
```

Метка на карту добавляется, но растягивается только в ширину, в высоту одна строка.
[image: API 2/.]

Ранее использовалась карта версии 2.0, там использовалась опция

```
preset: "twirl#lightblueStretchyIcon"
```

и всё работало как надо.

[image: API 2.0]

Как заставить иконку метки расшириться под контент в высоту на версии API 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Увы, никак. В версии 2.1 StretchyIcon не тянется в высоту.

Answer (score 0):

StretchyIcon в версии 2.1, действительно, не тянется в высоту, но можно добиться такого же результата и без неё.

Например, открывайте в нужной точке балун через `myMap.balloon.open()`

Если хочется навести красоту, можно задать свой макет балуна или сделать свой макет метки с многострочным описанием.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.761219, 37.578521],
    zoom: 10
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });


  // Открываем балун на карте (без привязки к геообъекту).
  myMap.balloon.open([55.761219, 37.578521], {
    contentBody: [
      '<i>Офис:</i>',
      '<br/>',
      '<strong>Название</strong>',
      '<br/>',
      'Адрес',
      '<br/>',
    ].join('')
  }, {
    // Опция: не показываем кнопку закрытия.
    closeButton: false,
    panelMaxMapArea: 0
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```